# Colocando evento de clique no botão que está numa Fragment, em uma Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Eu quero colocar um setOnClickListener no botão que está numa fragment, através da minha activity.

Seguem os códigos:

Activity:

```
private Button mButtonCriarConta;

//
onCreate da Activity...

mButtonCriarConta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_criar_button);
    Log.v("OnClick", "Nao Entrou no onClick");
    mButtonCriarConta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("OnClick", "Entrou no onClick");
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DonoDoProntuarioActivity.class);

            Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
            String email = mEmailCriarNovo.getText().toString();
            String senhaCriar = mSenhaCriarNovo.getText().toString();
            parametros.putString("email", email);
            parametros.putString("senha", senhaCriar);

            intent.putExtras(parametros);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Fragment onde está localizado o botão

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_criar_novo, container, false);

//resto do método
return view;}
```

XML da fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_novo_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/campoEmailNovoUsuario"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/campoSenhaNovo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_mostrar_senha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/chk_mostrar_senha" />

        <!-- <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>  -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_termos_criar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_criar_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_arredondado"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/acao_nova_conta"
            android:textColor="@color/branco"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Quando executo o programa no celular da que o app parou de funcionar e somente aparece o log antes de entrar no setOnClickListener, o que pode estar ocorrendo e como consertar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode/deve fazer isso assim. É o *fragment* que deve receber os eventos das suas *views*.

O método `findViewById()` só consegue encontrar as *views* que façam parte do layout passado ao método `setContentView()`.
Como o botão não está no *layout* da Activity, `findViewById(R.id.email_criar_button);` retorna `null`.

O habitual nestes casos é fazer com que o *fragment* informe a *Activity* que o botão foi clicado.

Para isso, na classe do *fragment*, defina uma interface que a *Actvity* deva implementar para que possa ser notificada:

```
public interface CreateEmailListener {
      public void onCreateEmail();
}
```

Declare uma variável privada no *Fragment* para guardar a referência da *Activity* que implemente a interface.

```
private CreateEmailListener mListener;
```

No evento *onAttach* do *Fragment* obtenha e guarde a referência à *Activity*.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (CreateEmailListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
        + " deve implementar CreateEmailListener");
    }
}
```

Deverá agora criar o *OnClickListener* para o botão dentro do método *onCreateView* do *fragment*:

```
private Button mButtonCriarConta;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_criar_novo, container, false);

    mButtonCriarConta = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.email_criar_button);

    mButtonCriarConta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Chame aqui o método da Activity
            mListener.onCreateEmail();
        }
    });

    //resto do método
    return view;
}
```

Agora só falta fazer a *Activity* implementar a interface *CreateEmailListener* e implementar o método `onCreateEmail()`

Se quiser passar algum valor do *fragment* para a *activity* declare o método `onCreateEmail()` de forma a aceitar parâmetros.